# Error while calling cloud framework endpoint api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am getting below error while accessing the api via explorer '_ah/api/explorer' or when api is called from the app.

Below is relevant piece from app.yaml and api implementation.

From other questions on stackoverflow it looks like this could happen if endpoint config is not deployed using gcloud service-management but event after uploading gatewayv1openapi.json I am getting similar error.

Is there something i need to change in api code or app.yaml? One more thing is that I have uploaded exact same codebase (only difference is other project id instead of ixp-test in app.yaml) to another old project and it works fine. Any newly created project is giving this error.

**/_ah/api/gateway/v1/invoke?alt=json**

no scheduler thread, scheduler.run() will be invoked by report(...) (/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints_management/control/client.py:235)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints_management/control/client.py", line 231, in start
    self._thread.start()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/background_thread/background_thread.py", line 108, in start
    start_new_background_thread(self.**bootstrap, ())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/background_thread/background_thread.py", line 87, in start_new_background_thread
    raise ERROR_MAPerror.application_error
FrontendsNotSupported
.
.
.
 (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import**(cumulative_path)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/main.py", line 18, in 
    api = endpoints.api_server([GatewayApi])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 514, in api_server
    controller)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints_management/control/wsgi.py", line 126, in add_all
    a_service = loader.load()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints_management/control/service.py", line 111, in load
    return self._load_func(**kw)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints_management/config/service_config.py", line 79, in fetch_service_config
    _log_and_raise(Exception, message_template.format(status_code))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ixp-test/20171013t215957.404774686885375478/server/lib/endpoints_management/config/service_config.py", line 127, in _log_and_raise
    raise exception_class(message)
Exception: Fetching service config failed (status code 403)

Below is the relevant config

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 0


env_variables:
  ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME: ixp-test.appspot.com
  ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION: 2017-08-13r0
```

**API**

```
@endpoints.api(name='gateway', version='v1')
class GatewayApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(
        GatewayRequest,
        GatewayResponse,
        path='invoke',
        http_method='POST',
        name='invoke')
    def invoke(self, request):
        pass
    @endpoints.method(
        GatewayRequest,
        GatewayResponse,
        path='invokeSecure',
        http_method='POST',
        name='invokeSecure',
        scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])
    def invoke_secure(self, request):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This might well happen if the service name in the gatewayv1openapi.json doesn't match the service name in the app.yaml; can you double-check that?

Comment: Yes they do match.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it. Issue was due to not updating

```
ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION: 2017-08-13r0
```

for new project. Value from old deployed project for which it was working caused the error.

from [getting started tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python)

```
gcloud service-management deploy echov1openapi.json
Service Configuration [2017-02-13-r2] uploaded for service [example-project.appspot.com]
```